# Adding a new column in SQL which calculates value from other columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I was trying to create a new column in SQL which has calculated values from other columns in the same table.

Please see the case below

```
col1 col2
A    1   
A    2
B    1
B    2
B    3
```

I need to create a new column 'col3' that finds the max of col2 grouped by col1. So the result i want is

```
col1 col2 col3
A    1    2   
A    2    2
B    1    3
B    2    3
B    3    3
```

I would like to know if a query can be something along the below lines

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD col3 AS (SELECT max(col2) GROUPBY col1)
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? The answer depends on the product.

Comment: Its generally a bad idea putting calulated values in the database. They normally end up wrong because some bit of code forgets to maintain them. Instead calculate the value in the query that gets the data from that database when you want to show it

Comment: @RiggsFolly If they are calculated, they are not stored inside the database, but calculated when queried, unless `PERSISTED` is used. And then they should normally recalculate themselves. However, I'm not sure how `PERSISTED` would perform in this situation since I believe `PERSISTED` columns only recalculate when fields referenced in their own record are updated.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need an `ALTER` statement and can get the extra column in your `SELECT` query like

```
select col1, col2, max(col2) as col3
from tbl1
group by col1
```

Comment: Should have waited for your answer, and saved myself the effort of commenting. :) UV Totally agree

Comment: @SandipPatel, Yes it will if OP is using `SQL Server` else no.

Comment: i wonder if this will return an aggregated output that gives unique values of col1 since we are grouping it. however my output needs to populate all the values of col1

Comment: @user2604789 I doubt you can do this in 1 go, since you require all data to make a proper aggregate. You'd first have to have your data, then calculate those fields. If anyone can do that all in 1 go, i'm interested to read about it.

Comment: i use it in SAS (Proc SQL). i dont think it has ALTER table option

Comment: If i use the above statement and create a new table, then join it with the old table - that should work i suppose?